# Timestamp in database query in linux vs windows on Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm having a strange issue with some legacy code.  This works when I run it in windows but not when I run it from linux.

```
...
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT MODTS from MYTBL WHERE ID = 'X'");
rs.next();
Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(rs.getString(1));
System.out.println("TS: '" + ts + "'");

PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * from MYTBL WHERE MODTS = ?");
ps.setTimestamp(1, ts);

System.out.println("FOUND? " + ps.executeQuery().next());
```

Now, both environments are connecting to the same database, both environments print out the value '2013-03-10 03:35:16.0' for the TS variable.  However, in windows I get "FOUND? true" in linux I get "FOUND? false".

Any idea what could be going on here?

NOTE: I know this is not the optimal way to use JDBC here, but this is legacy code which I can't make changes to and I'm trying to figure out why it's not working properly in one environment.

The DB environment is Oracle 11g using ojdbc6.jar

EDIT:  What's more strange is that this doesn't happen on ALL timestamps, just certain ones.  I really don't get what is going on here...

Comment: What data type is the `MODTS` column? What are your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` settings from each platform (which may be derived from your Java locale)? It looks like an implicit conversion problem, but not sure...

Comment: Does `ts.getTime()` return the same `long` value in both instances? `Timestamp.valueOf(String s)` creates a date in the system's timezone.

Comment: I'll check those values and get back, also, ts.getTime() returns the same, I also figured out if I do it right and use rs.getTimestamp() instead of the String conversion it still fails on linux for some of them.

Comment: When I query from both windows and linux, I get the values 'DD-MON-RR' and 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM' for NLS date and timestamp formats.  Again though, the strange this is it doesn't do this for all timestamps, only some of them and it still has the issue when I skip the string formatting part and just directly use rs.getTimestamp(1) to put in my next query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I was able to find the solution.  The problem still alludes me but this solves it at least.

Change:

```
ps.setTimestamp(1, ts);
```

To:

```
ps.setTimestamp(1, ts, Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault()));
```

Comment: Great, +1. I was going to suggest you look into v$sql_bind_capture to find out what the actual bind values were.